# Modify data from a different Activity in Android

Tags: android, variables, android-activity, share

I've been just wondering if there is a way to modify variables from a different activity from which they were created. Precisely, I would like to modify a list in Activity1 from Activity 2, is there a way to give a reference to that list from the other activity? `putExtra()` method does not accept List as input parameter and I don't think `startActivityForResponse()` is what I'm looking for either. I don't know if some kind of shared variables exist or something alike.

Is it possible to do that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

May be this is not the very good solution but what you can do is that you can create DataManager as single Instanse that Hold Linklist of data. In each activity you can get instance of data-manager and update data in it.

Answer (score 0):

You *can* pass the entire list as an extra, you just need to serialize it by making it a parcelable first.

`A Container for a message (data and object references) that can be sent through an IBinder. A Parcel can contain both flattened data that will be unflattened on the other side of the IPC`

A bit confusing to understand, but all it really does is flatten the data into strings/ints/other primitive types so that it can be passed easily. On the other side, it's re-build into your list structure.

This is the tutorial I used when I did something similar:

http://prasanta-paul.blogspot.ca/2010/06/android-parcelable-example.html

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to try this out now!